# GRAL - Axis styling - Keeping same Y axis across plots

Tags: java, charts, plot, axis-labels

I have a plot that I've created with GRAL:

[GRAL plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZD2p.png)

The problems I'm having are with the axis. Basically I'd like the Y axis to run from 0 .. 4 in every graph, and I can't find a way to force this behaviour. If I zoom out there is extra increments, but I'd like 0 .. 4 show up in the unzoomed plots.

I've also tried using `setCustomTicks` but the default ticks remain, is there a way to remove them and only use custom ones?

Help would be greatly appreciated!

The code for my plot is:

```
int[][] seq_data_200 = chunkArray(seq_data, 200);
DataTable[] listData = new DataTable[seq_data_200.length];
for (int i = 0; i < seq_data_200.length; i++){
    DataTable data = new DataTable(Integer.class, Integer.class);
    for (int j = 0; j < seq_data_200[i].length; j++) {
        data.add(j, seq_data_200[i][j]);
    }
    listData[i] = data;
}

panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(seq_data_200.length,1,20,20));

for (int i = 0; i < listData.length; i++) {
    XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(listData[i]);

    LineRenderer lines = new DefaultLineRenderer2D();
    plot.setLineRenderer(listData[i], lines);
    Color color = new Color(0.0f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    plot.getPointRenderer(listData[i]).setColor(color);
    plot.getLineRenderer(listData[i]).setColor(color);

    double insetsTop = 20.0, insetsLeft = 60.0, insetsBottom = 60.0, insetsRight = 40.0;
    plot.setInsets(new Insets2D.Double(insetsTop, insetsLeft, insetsBottom, insetsRight));
    plot.getTitle().setText(getTitle(i, sequence));

    plot.getAxisRenderer(XYPlot.AXIS_X).setLabel("Bases");
    plot.getAxisRenderer(XYPlot.AXIS_X).setCustomTicks(getTicks(i, sequence));

    plot.getAxisRenderer(XYPlot.AXIS_Y).setLabel("Number of " + nucleo + "'s");
    plot.getAxisRenderer(XYPlot.AXIS_Y).setMinorTicksVisible(false);
    plot.getAxisRenderer(XYPlot.AXIS_Y).setTickSpacing(1);

    panel.add(new InteractivePanel(plot), BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a somewhat hackish fix that works in the interim:

GRAL decides on axis height using the `DataTable`. It uses the max and min values of the table to define the viewport.

So if you add two pieces of Data:

`DataTable.add(x,minY)`

`DataTable.add(x,maxY)`

They'll be some spurious data on the graph, but the viewport will resize itself to your desired axis. Since these points are added at the end, they tend to be obscured somewhat, and are easy to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

The following method worked for me:

```
plot.getAxis(XYPlot.AXIS_X).setRange(0.0, 4.0);
plot.getAxis(XYPlot.AXIS_Y).setRange(0.0, 20.0);
```